# Android studio subversion does not showing all revision

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

[image]

Revision 14and 15 not showing in the list any one knows why may it not     showing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the revision all of the project, not only the file. If you see only the file, you will see only the revision of file.

Comment: Hi adam thanks for your answer , The screen shot that i have attached is not only the file. It is my entire project svn revision history and each of them is not regarding with sigle file each of them is consist of multilple file edits and there is 2 more revision betweeen 13 and 16 that i have commited in my svn successfully but now it is not showing